# Comparison between point and integer ('int' and 'void *') using NULL

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I get the error message "Comparison between point and integer ('int' and 'void *') using NULL" before I run the application. The strange thing is the application runs perfect every time. Here is a snippet of the code.

```
- (IBAction) addButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    int timeStamp = nil;

    timeStamp = self.hourTextField.intValue;


    if (timeStamp == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Nothing here for ya");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"monkey shit");
    }

}
```

I get the error at the line.

```
    if (timeStamp == NULL) {
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NULL is meant to be used for pointer comparisons only. `timeStamp` is an int, not a pointer, so the comparison doesn't really make sense. The compiler sees the comparison with NULL and says, "maybe he thinks timeStamp is a pointer, but it's not, so I better warn him". In this case, you probably want to check that `timeStamp` is not *zero*:

```
if (timeStamp == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Nothing here for ya");
}
```

Indeed, that's actually what your code is doing now, because in reality `NULL` *is* 0.

Also worth noting is that the compiler is issuing a warning, not an error. The important difference is that warnings are things the compiler thinks might be a mistake, but which don't prevent the program from compiling. Errors actually prevent the compiler from doing its job, and cause compilation to fail. You should *never* ignore warnings. You can tell the compiler to [treat warnings as errors](http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/treat-warnings-as-errors.html), to enforce discipline on yourself.

Comment: You should **never accept warnings**.  Even a warning you understand is indication that you haven't told the compiler "No, really, I know what I'm doing".  A correctly written program should have zero warnings and turning on *treat warnings as errors* should be actively encouraged.

Comment: @bbum, thanks. I revised my answer to be more forceful about that.

Comment: I'll further add that if you get into the habit of ignoring any warnings at all, it becomes too easy to miss warnings that you shouldn't be ignoring. I ALWAYS enable "treat warnings as errors". Clean compiles are a GOOD thing.

Comment: @rmaddy, I think you meant "too easy to miss warnings". I agree. (I do wish Interface Builder wasn't so warning happy with no way to configure them like you can with the compiler...)

Comment: This is also true of `nil`, which is the null pointer for object pointers. Still a pointer, so it's still wrong. The initializer should be `0` (or some other value that the user can never validly enter).

Comment: Thanks guys just wanted to confirm that the solution was 0 instead of NULL